# Best legal way to check arguments with eachother in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I want to say in python don't use for example '-a' switch with '-b'. How can I do that in python?

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'a:b:')
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt == '-a':
        after = str(arg)
    elif opt == '-b':
        before = int(arg)
```

for example:

```
# python script.py -a aaa -b bbb
  don't use -b arg with -a
```

Comment: [argparse](http://pymotw.com/2/argparse/) makes life easy

Comment: What is your suggestion?

Comment: Respect PEP8 please, my eyes hurt.

Comment: Mutual Exclusion with argparse:  https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion

Comment: I am not really keen on using argparser... other solutions?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not keen on it when it can do what you want with minimal fuzz?

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
mut_exc_opts = ['-a','-b']
opts_only = map(lambda (opt,arg): opt, opts)
matches = [x for x in mut_exc_opts if x in opts_only]
if len(matches) > 1:
    print "do not use options", ', '.join(mut_exc_opts), "together"
```

It works for any number of options and for any combination of options that must be mutually exclusive.

Tested on python 2.7